# Pass touch to underlaying button of UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I've got a modal view that has "Cancel" button (the button dismisses modal).
In the modal, I'm shoving a small UIPopover.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

When the UIPopover is visible, if uset touches "Cancel" it will do both:

- hide popover (it's happening now, since that's the click outside popup)
- hide modal - as if user touched "Cancel" without popup

Is there a way to do it?

UIPopoverControllerDelegate is not providing any help (or I'm not seeing it :) )

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before presenting the popover, add the Cancel button to the popover's passthroughViews array:

```
popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cancelButton];
```

This will let the Cancel button respond to touches while the popover is displayed without automatically dismissing the popover.

Then in your Cancel button's action method, call `dismissPopoverAnimated:` on the popover before dismissing the modal view.

You'll need to keep a reference to the popover in an ivar (eg. popoverController) to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly the property I needed :) Btw I cannot upvote, not enough rep :/